# Pronunciation of Ernst Robert Curtius

Tags: pronunciation, literature, phonetics

I've been reading a book by Ernst Robert Curtius, a 20th. cent. German philologist, and sources online suggest that Curtius is pronounced as "Court-zi-us." I'm wondering where that "z/s" sound after the "t" comes from, and why it's pronounced like that rather than "Court-ius"?

Thanks!

Comment: How is "Court-zi-us" pronounced like?

Comment: You should probably learn some IPA to understand the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--I've been trying, with mixed success, to learn it.

Comment: A little while back, I asked a question about the pronunciation of "ti" as "zi"; some of the answers there might be of interest to you: [Have spelling reformers ever proposed rewriting “-ti-” as “-zi-” when it is pronounced that way?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48314/have-spelling-reformers-ever-proposed-rewriting-ti-as-zi-when-it-is-pron)

Answer (score 4):

The same pronunciation also applies to the chemist [Curtius](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodor_Curtius_(Chemiker)) and all others with the same surname.

In words of Latin origin that end in *-tium, -tius, -tion, -tial, -tiell* and others with the general pattern of *ti + vowel*, the t underwent softening in various degrees in different European languages. In English in a word such as *nation*, the *ti* is effecticely pronounced as if it were a *sh*. In French, the *t* turns into an /s/ sound so the result is something like [nasjõ]. In German, instead of turning into a full fricative like in English or French the resulting sound is an affricate /ts/.

In writing, the /ts/ sound is generally represented by the letter *z* in German. (The sound commonly represented by the letter *z* in English, /z/, is represented by a single *s* in German – but not all dialects use it.) So to a German, instead of saying ‘an *s* has been added’ the typical thought process would be ‘*t* turned into *z*’ – or possibly, since *tz* is another possible spelling for the /ts/ sound, ‘a *z* was added’.

In the 1996 spelling reform, this pronunciation was reflected in the spelling of a couple of words such as *Potenzial* which may now be spelt with *z* instead of *t*.

Answer (score 2):

The name is pronounced like the word short "kurz", so the name is pronounced as [kʊʁt͡sius].
Here is an audio sample. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kurz#Pronunciation_2

The phenomenon responsible is called yod-coalescense. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-coalescence here English examples, the only difference being that in German, t before i is pronounced like "ts".

Answer (score 2):

In words of Latin origin, *ti* followed by another vowel is pronounced [tsi] as it was in post-classical Latin. Compare:

> Nation
>   Konsortium
>   Initiative

Answer (score 1):

This is the way the combination ...ti*(other vowel)*... is pronounced in German. In this combination the "t" is pronounced as if it was a "z". There are a few words with this combination where the spelling was changed in the spelling reform from 1996, e.g. *Potential* became *Potenzial*, making the spelling matching the pronounciation, but many others are still written with "ti".
The question, **why** it is pronounciated like this is as useful or useless as to ask why in English the "ti" is pronounced like "sh", e.g. you write *nation* but pronounce it like *naysh'n".

Comment: They come from English backgroudn with "z as in pulveriZe". So your post is somewhat misleading, I think.